# Python & MySQL -- find all rows within 3 seconds of one another

Tags: python, mysql, datetime, pandas, timedelta

I have physical devices that are part of a game. Players get points for activating one of these devices. I am trying to incorporate logic to flag 'cheaters'. All activations of a device count as one 'event' if they occur within a 2.5 second span. I am trying to identify spans of a 'cheating' player (someone just rapidly jamming the button over and over). In the database, this would look like multiple rows with the same `deviceAddress`, with `eventValues` of 3 or 4 and with `eventTimes` within 3 seconds of one another.

I am having a very hard time trying to figure out how to appropriately find events within 3 seconds of one another. Here is the error message I'm currently getting:

```
if delta <= (timePreviousRow - timedelta(seconds=3)) and devPreviousRow == devThisRow:
TypeError: can't compare datetime.timedelta to datetime.datetime
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my MySQL query, set to the variable `cheatFinder`:

```
SELECT
eventTime,
deviceAddress,
node_id,
eventType,
eventValue,
sequence
FROM device_data
WHERE eventTime >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
AND eventType = 1
AND eventValue BETWEEN 3 AND 4
ORDER BY deviceAddress, eventTime;
```

Here are the first 10 results:

```
+---------------------+------------------+------------+-----------+------------+----------+
| eventTime           | deviceAddress | node_id | eventType | eventValue | sequence |
+---------------------+------------------+------------+-----------+------------+----------+
| 2017-01-26 21:19:03 |           776128 |        221 |         1 | 03         |        3 |
| 2017-01-26 21:48:19 |           776128 |        221 |         1 | 03         |        4 |
| 2017-01-27 06:45:50 |           776128 |        221 |         1 | 04         |       18 |
| 2017-01-27 12:41:03 |           776128 |        221 |         1 | 03         |       24 |
| 2017-01-26 23:03:18 |          6096372 |        301 |         1 | 03         |      119 |
| 2017-01-27 00:21:47 |          6096372 |        301 |         1 | 03         |      120 |
| 2017-01-26 23:50:27 |         27038894 |        157 |         1 | 03         |      139 |
| 2017-01-27 01:19:42 |         29641083 |        275 |         1 | 03         |      185 |
| 2017-01-27 00:10:13 |         30371381 |        261 |         1 | 03         |       82 |
| 2017-01-27 00:53:45 |         30371381 |        261 |         1 | 03         |       87 |
+---------------------+------------------+------------+-----------+------------+----------+
```

Here is the Python method in question:

```
import mysql.connector
import pandas
from datetime import datetime,timedelta

. . .     

def findBloodyCheaters(self):
    self.cursor.execute(cheatFinder)
    resultSet = self.cursor.fetchall()
    targetDF = pandas.DataFrame(columns=['eventTime', 'deviceAddress', 'gateway_id', 'eventType', 'eventValue',
                                         'sequence'])
    timePreviousRow = None
    devPreviousRow = None
    for row in resultSetRaw:
        if timePreviousRow is None and devPreviousRow is None:
            timePreviousRow = row[0]
            devPreviousRow = row[1]
        elif timePreviousRow is not None and devPreviousRow is not None:
            timeThisRow = row[0]
            devThisRow = row[1]
            delta = timePreviousRow - timeThisRow
            print(delta)
            if delta <= (timePreviousRow - timedelta(seconds=3)) and devPreviousRow == devThisRow:
                targetDF.append(row)
            timePreviousRow = timeThisRow
            devPreviousRow = devThisRow
            print(targetDF)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you're trying to compare `delta` which is a `timedelta` object to `(timePreviousRow - timedelta(seconds=3))` which is a `datetime` object. I would try to compare `delta` to just `timedelta(seconds=3)` so your code would look like:

```
if delta <= timedelta(seconds=3) and devPreviousRow == devThisRow:
```

Comment: I think that did it, @wpercy. Thank you for sticking with me on this one.

Comment: I am confused by the behavior of `timedelta`, however. Why can't I just say, `if delta <= 3`?

Comment: Because `delta` is a `timedelta` object and `3` is an integer. Python isn't smart enough to know that you want `3` to mean 3 seconds. It could mean 3 hours or 3 days or 3 years, so you need to tell it exactly what it needs to compare to (in this case a `timedelta` object with a value of 3 seconds